# PHP preg_match to filter publisher header title

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, space

I would like to retrieve the publisher string out of a long header.

`- THE TRIBUNE-JOURNAL (Johnstown, Pa.) - The 5 Best Places To Live If You Hate Winter`

I have tried `preg_match(' /-(.*?)-/ ', $publisher_title, $pub_dashed);`

it outputs: - THE TRIBUNE- [bad]

it is supposed to be: - THE TRIBUNE-JOURNAL (Johnstown, Pa.) - [good]

note that the publisher is most of the times without dash,

for example:  - Reuters - 2013 Best of Year Camera Awards

it outputs: - Reuters - [good]

Comment: The short answer is that you won't be able to reliably do this, short of having a lookup table of all known publishers you expect to appear. You can change `.*?` to `.*` to match until the last `-` but then this won't work if the rest of the title has a hyphen in it. Alternatively you will have to reformat how you do your headers to make a unique delimiter between publisher and rest of header

Comment: you could also do `preg_match('/-(.*?)- /', $publisher_title, $pub_dashed);` (notice the space after the last hyphen) this will *probably* catch most of your needs, including your tribune-journal example, but it's not guaranteed to work...

Comment: `preg_match('/-(.*?)- /', $publisher_title, $pub_dashed);` works!

Assuming there will be a max of one dash in the publisher name.

Comment: is the publisher always UPPERCASE?

Comment: No- see the example with Reuters above..

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/\A- (.+?) - /', $publisher_title, $pub_dashed);
```

Comment: What is the difference between '/-(.*?)- /' and '/\A- (.+?) - /'

Comment: @AlbuquerqueWebDesign: `\A` is an anchor and means "start of the string". CertaiN assumes that the title is always at the start of the string.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** `/- (.+?) -[^-]*$/` ?

Capturing this string:
`- THE TRIBUNE - JOURNAL (Johnstown, Pa.) - The 5 Best Places To Live If You Hate Winter`

It returns on match 1 `THE TRIBUNE - JOURNAL (Johnstown, Pa.)`

It works on the principle of finding the last non-hyphen, and removing it. It will also work on your original example where there are *no* spaces between TRIBUNE-JOURNAL.

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/cL2bB7

Caveat: if there's a dash in the caption, it's not going to work.

**Option 2:**

If the publisher is always UPPERCASE, you could use `/- ([A-Z\s\-]+\s\(.*?\))/`, which will look for all UPPERCASE letters, space, or dash, followed by text wrapped in parentheses ( ).